# Tag I can't find: "insider" puzzle

Tags: support, tags

I just finished checking all Puzzling site tags. I recall a tag that meant that the puzzle involved knowledge about the site itself, and maybe a user, but I didn't see it. Was it deleted? Did I not notice it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We at least don't have such a tag right now. (Speaking as someone who's read through all our tags repeatedly). However, [knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) works for any sort of specific knowledge required.

I would urge you to be careful when referencing specific users. Please, **please** get permission first. Also, be aware that users change. Activity goes up and down, profile pictures and "About Me"s are edited, puzzles are posted and deleted, etc. See [this meta answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6834/69582)